# Why doesn't my code work in chrome? It works in internet explorer

Tags: html, google-chrome

I wrote this a long time ago. I barely understand html and it was a nightmare to write but it worked. It was just my way of making it easier to access my emulators but it only worked in internet explorer. It won't work in chrome but it does show up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>

<script
type = "text/javascript"
language = "javascript">
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("NES").onmouseover = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
this.style.color = "#00FFFF";
}
document.getElementById("NES").onmouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
this.style.color = "#000000";
}
document.getElementById("SNES").onmouseover = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
this.style.color = "#00FFFF";
}
document.getElementById("SNES").onmouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
this.style.color = "#000000";
}
document.getElementById("Sega").onmouseover = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
this.style.color = "#00FFFF";
}
document.getElementById("Sega").onmouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
this.style.color = "#000000";
}
document.getElementById("Gamecube").onmouseover = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
this.style.color = "#00FFFF";
}
document.getElementById("Gamecube").onmouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
this.style.color = "#000000";
}
document.getElementById("GBC").onmouseover = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
this.style.color = "#00FFFF";
}
document.getElementById("GBC").onmouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
this.style.color = "#000000";
}
document.getElementById("GBA").onmouseover = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
this.style.color = "#00FFFF";
}
document.getElementById("GBA").onmouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
this.style.color = "#000000";
}
document.getElementById("N64").onmouseover = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
this.style.color = "#00FFFF";
}
document.getElementById("N64").onmouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
this.style.color = "#000000";
}
document.getElementById("NDS").onmouseover = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
this.style.color = "#00FFFF";
}
document.getElementById("NDS").onmouseout = function() {
this.style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
this.style.color = "#000000";
}

} </script>

<script
type = "text/javascript"
language = "javascript">
function RunNES() {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("file:///E:/Leisure/Games/Emulators/NES/NES%20System/nintendulator.exe", 1, false);
}
function RunSNES() {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("file:///E:/Leisure/Games/Emulators/SNES/SNES%20System/zsnesw.exe", 1, false);
}
function RunSega() {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("file:///E:/Leisure/Games/Emulators/Sega/Genesis/Fusion364/Fusion.exe", 1, false);
}
function RunGamecube() {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("file:///E:/Leisure/Games/Emulators/Gamecube/Dolphin/Dolphin.exe", 1, false);
}
function RunGBC() {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("file:///E:/Leisure/Games/Emulators/GBC/TGB-Dual.exe", 1, false);
}
function RunGBA() {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("file:///E:/Leisure/Games/Emulators/GBA/GBALink.exe", 1, false);
}
function RunN64() {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("file:///E:/Leisure/Games/Emulators/N64/Console/Project64.exe", 1, false);
}
function RunNDS() {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("file:///E:/Leisure/Games/Emulators/DS/Desmume/DeSmuME_0.9.10_x64.exe", 1, false);
}
</script>

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:960px; height:540px; z-index: 0"
src = "Images/Background.png">

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:150px; left:50px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index: 1"
src = "Images/NES.png">
<input
style = "background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000; opacity:1; position:absolute; top:250px; left:50px; width:100px; height:20px; z-index: 1"
id = "NES"
type = "button"
value = "Nintendo"
onMouseover = "CursorIn()"
onMouseout = "CursorOut()"
onclick = "RunNES()"
/>

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:150px; left:200px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index: 1"
src = "Images/SNES.png">
<input
style = "background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000; opacity:1; position:absolute; top:250px; left:200px; width:100px; height:20px; z-index: 1"
id = "SNES"
type = "button"
value = "Super NES"
onMouseover = "CursorIn()"
onMouseout = "CursorOut()"
onclick = "RunSNES()"
/>

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:275px; left:50px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index: 1"
src = "Images/Sega.png">
<input
style = "background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000; opacity:1; position:absolute; top:375px; left:50px; width:100px; height:20px; z-index: 1"
id = "Sega"
type = "button"
value = "Sega Genesis"
onMouseover = "CursorIn()"
onMouseout = "CursorOut()"
onclick = "RunSega()"
/>

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:275px; left:200px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index: 1"
src = "Images/Gamecube.png">
<input
style = "background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000; opacity:1; position:absolute; top:375px; left:200px; width:100px; height:20px; z-index: 1"
id = "Gamecube"
type = "button"
value = "Gamecube"
onMouseover = "CursorIn()"
onMouseout = "CursorOut()"
onclick = "RunGamecube()"
/>

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:150px; left:660px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index: 1"
src = "Images/GBC.png">
<input
style = "background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000; opacity:1; position:absolute; top:250px; left:660px; width:100px; height:20px; z-index: 1"
id = "GBC"
type = "button"
value = "Gameboy Clr"
onMouseover = "CursorIn()"
onMouseout = "CursorOut()"
onclick = "RunGBC()"
/>

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:150px; left:810px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index: 1"
src = "Images/GBA.png">
<input
style = "background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000; opacity:1; position:absolute; top:250px; left:810px; width:100px; height:20px; z-index: 1"
id = "GBA"
type = "button"
value = "Gameboy Adv"
onMouseover = "CursorIn()"
onMouseout = "CursorOut()"
onclick = "RunGBA()"
/>

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:275px; left:660px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index: 1"
src = "Images/N64.png">
<input
style = "background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000; opacity:1; position:absolute; top:375px; left:660px; width:100px; height:20px; z-index: 1"
id = "N64"
type = "button"
value = "Nintendo 64"
onMouseover = "CursorIn()"
onMouseout = "CursorOut()"
onclick = "RunN64()"
/>

<img
style = "opacity:1; position:absolute; top:275px; left:810px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index: 1"
src = "Images/NDS.png">
<input
style = "background-color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000; opacity:1; position:absolute; top:375px; left:810px; width:100px; height:20px; z-index: 1"
id = "NDS"
type = "button"
value = "Nintendo DS"
onMouseover = "CursorIn()"
onMouseout = "CursorOut()"
onclick = "RunNDS()"
/>

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using ActiveX objects. Those are not JavaScript, and they are only available on Internet Explorer. It is not possible to execute code that uses ActiveX controls on any other browser.

Comment: How do I fix it? I'm not a smart person. I barely understand RbxLua, even less about html.

Comment: You ask your users to install Internet Explorer, and to add your website to the trusted zone. There is zero chance of any other browser running executable files for you - nobody else is stupid enough to allow such a huge security hole into their browser, given that it allows for a total takeover of the client machine. Let me rephrase that: you fix this in the same way you fix banks not giving you money with "pretty please" instead of your signature and ID: you *don't*.